# Optimizing generated quantum state with complex variables in python

Tags: python, physics

I need an advice. I'm trying to prepare a superposition of squeezed states to match the desired target_ket. What is the best way to find the best combination of parameters so that final fidelity |<Output|Target>|^2 is as close to 1 as possible? I'm aware this could be solved by minimize if I optimize real and imaginary parts separately, but I'd rather not do that since that would double the number of parameters making it harder to use this for superpositions of more states. The function itself should take alpha as an input, perform the optimization and then output parameters which provide the best output ket.

I'd be happy for any advice :)

```
def function(alpha):

    # for given alpha, a target ket is constructed
    target_ket = (qt.coherent(N, -alpha / np.sqrt(2)) +
                  qt.coherent(N, alpha / np.sqrt(2)) +
                  np.sqrt(2) * qt.coherent(N, 0)).unit()
    # then I want to construct an output ket
    out_ket = (c1 * qt.squeeze(N, p1) * qt.basis(N, 0) +
               c2 * qt.squeeze(N, p2) * qt.basis(N, 2) +
               c3 * qt.squeeze(N, p3) * qt.basis(N, 4) +
               c4 * qt.squeeze(N, p4) * qt.basis(N, 6)).unit()
    inner_product = (qt.dag(out_ket) * target_ket).norm ** 2
    return c1, c2, c3,...,p4
    # parametes c1,..,c4 and p,1..,p4 are complex and I want to optimize them so inner_product goes to 1
```

After consulting chatgpt I've tried using the minimize function, but couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.